# If $E$ is an equivalence relation over $X$, then $X/E$ is a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that using the ZFC axioms.

I know that $E$ is a set, I have also managed to prove that each equivalence class $D\subseteq X\; $ is a set.
Can I use the Axion of union and denote that $\bigcup D \;_ {\text{D is an equivalence class}}$ is a set and that $\bigcup D \;_ {\text{D is an equivalence class}}=X/E$ ?

Comment: If $E$ is an equivalence relation, and $D$ is one of its equivalence classes, then $D\notin E$; $D\subseteq X$.

Comment: What is $X/E$?  Is it a subset of $X$ with representatives of distinct equivalence classes?  Or maybe the partition of $X$ into equivalence classes?

Comment: @BrianMoehring: Presumably $X/E$ is the set of equivalence classes.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks i'll edit that

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry, I assumed it was a well known notion

Comment: @GoodWilly: It’s pretty standard; I’d have been surprised if you were using any other definition of it.

Comment: The set $\cup D$ is just $X$; it’s not what you want. What you want is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$. So you need a formula to apply to subsets of $X$ that amounts to “is an equivalence class of $X$ modulo $E$”, and then use the Axiom of Specification/Separation on $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott My main problem was with the last equality.  The union of equivalence classes is $X$ itself, so it looked like a good place to start was to formally define $X/E$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How could I specify that formula explicitly?

Comment: Well, presumably that is the key of this problem. You want something along the lines of “there exists $x\in X$ such that for all $y\in X$, $y\in D$ if and only if $xEy$”.